# WebView change audio output device

Tags: android, audio, webview, webrtc, peerjs

How can I change the audio output of WebView from loudspeaker to earpiece? I tried this code, but it is not working

```
    private fun setupAudio() {
        val am = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        am.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
        am.stopBluetoothSco()
        am.isSpeakerphoneOn=false
        Log.e("Foo","Current mode is ${am.mode}")
    }
```

Have permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, the trick is to call `setupAudio()` function after the playback starts.

Answer (score 0):

Stop send and received in BT, turn off BT and then turn off speakerphone. This is to turn on earpiece.

```
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION); //
        am.stopBluetoothSco(); // stop send and receive
        am.setBluetoothScoOn(false); // turn off bluetooth
        am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); // true to turn on speakerphone; false to turn it off
```

To turn on internal speaker -

```
   am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
   am.stopBluetoothSco();
   am.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
   am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: Still, the audio is coming from the loudspeaker.